# How can I make @Import function in my main.scss global?

Tags: css, node.js, import, sass, global-variables

Hey guys I'm a newbie learning sass and I'm using node.js and cmd to serve as my local compiler. I have a main.scss file where I have done all my @imports. [This is an image of main.scss with all imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtiGQ.png) Anytime I try to save my work, I get an error saying my variables are undefined, meanwhile they are.
[This is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbGJp.png)
[And this is where the supposed error is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Nd5.jpg) [Meanwhile my variable.scss is intact, take a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k29K.png)

**So I guess the question is, how do I make my @imports global in my project.**

Answer (score 0):

Double Check your variable `$color-primary-light` if it is define in your scss file. Or change the `@import "base/typography` function and transfer it to the upper most part of your `main.scss`.

Scss reads imports from top to bottom and there are some css specificity/hierarchy of css when compiling them into one css file.

```
@import "base/typography
@import "base/base
@import "base/animations
@import "base/utilities
```

Comment: Glad it works for you. you can mark as check to this answer as to some other viewers or developers might check your question and they can find the answer perfectly.